# Should I put a comma to make this sentence correct?

Tags: punctuation

As I am preparing for an English exam, I have questions about what I read here and then so I really appreciate if you can tell me if this sentence is correct in terms of its grammar. To be more specific, I was confused that why there is no comma after "evident" but even after putting comma in between, it is still quite vague with a second language learner like me.

> A similar growth in the figure for children was evident reaching 25% in 2007 and around 24% in the final year.

Also, should I put comma after "items" and "expenditure"?

> Turkey spent most on these items at just 4% of their national expenditure which is around double that of Spain (1.8%)

Comment: I would use a comma—but I'd also make it *was evident,* ***as it reached***. The use of *reaching* (comma or not) seems odd.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Your suggested rewrite is the one that sounds odd to me. It is strange to point out the reason why the growth was evident, and makes far more sense to add further details (the levels in 07 and the later year).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The increase in the numbers *makes* the growth evident. If  you're looking at a series of numbers, year over year, with most at 4%, and you suddenly see a couple around 25%, my natural impulse would be to say something like, "Look! *Evidently*, there was growth here."

Comment: @Jason Bassford Do I remember correctly that your day job is connected with stats? This is ELU, where the content, not the vehicle, is in focus. Graphs etc are secondary. _And I taught maths._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Language serves no shared purpose if it doesn't convey meaning from one person to another. It's fine if you interpret *evident* in a different way, but that's not the only interpretation. We will both leave our own comments and let others sort them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you google the phrase "was evident reaching" you'll find similar constructions, many of which have either a comma (most frequent) or a dash (a few) after "evident". Following the herd, I'd probably stick in a comma.

Comment: The comma here indicates a slight pause if the sentence is read aloud. It is not really a matter of grammar but it helps the reader avoid wondering for a moment what 'evident reaching' is.

Comment: @JeremyC I couldn't agree more. But this might have some hardliners spitting feathers.